# Codename one latest build issue with fonts?

Tags: java, android, mobile, cross-platform, codenameone

I am trying to do a build for android on codenameone , after the last update when I send a build for android it converts all buttons and label text to UPPERCASE
whatever the text [was written in]

any build hint or fix to this issue

Regards,

Comment: For buttons might be possible with latest version but for textview not!

Comment: @Naitik but how can I handle the buttons and labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this for the long version https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-material-buttons.html

Here is the short version, you can disable this using:

- `myButton.setCapsText(false);`
- `Button.setCapsTextDefault(false);`
- Define the theme constant `capsButtonTextBool` to false

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest Material Design guidelines, buttons use ALL CAPS for text, regardless of the capitalization you pass in.

https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style

To prevent this, set this attribute on your `<Button>` tag:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Comment: P , ok that works for android but there are a theme constant that controls that as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
 <Button        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```